# Lost ability to boot to any other disk after boot-repair recommended

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, gparted, bootloader

I have many disks with OS'es.

On one disk I had Ubuntu 16 and Windows 7 dual boot,
and start OS'es on other disks from it's GRUB menu.

Everything was fine before I used gparted for it's repartition:

on Windows7 side of this disk I have lost 70Gb of information (it had status "used" and after gpated became free) all folders became read only,
some of installed programs became unable to execute from windowses on another disks, and get an error than try'ed to boot to this windows7.

Due to recommendations to correct gparted harm I've typed from live ubuntu usb:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

afterwards in boot menu I see the ONLY variant to boot in ubuntu from this disk.

Due to recommendations I've tried:
advanced options"
 "OS to boot by default:" there was Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 7, so I choose Windows 7 and than 'Apply

It didn't helped. 
Also restoring windows... in boot repair->
advanced options-> other didn't helped

Where are OS'es from other disks gone?

Why when I disconnect this disk from computer I can't boot to another systems and just got `error: no such device: adf2edd-8c51.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>`

How to restore boot menu for all disks?

UPD: for some of other disk gparted now start to write:

> Unable to read the contnts of this file system!

should I check and repair it in GParted or it will cause new round of problems?

Comment: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info If you did not use Windows to resize the NTFS partition, it may have locked it up in gparted as NTFS must have a chkdsk immediately after a resize. Always use Windows tools for Windows and Linux tools for Linux. Do not attempt to create partitions with Windows as it may convert to dynamic from basic partitions which makes a real mess of things.

Comment: [https://paste2.org/3gCIY87v ]

boot-info, generated now. May I clarify:  next time before gparted I should unallocate some of windows partition in WIndows and only afterwards to unite this unallocated part to linux partition using gparted?

Comment: I always suggest using Windows tools for Windows & Linux tools for Linux. So best to use Windows to shrink NTFS partitions and reboot as it always needs chkdsk after a resize. And then use gparted or installer to create new partitions. With multiple drives, I do not like Boot-Repairs auto-fix that installs grub to every drive. You want to keep Windows boot loaders in sda, sdb,sdc and only have grub in sdd and set BIOS to boot sdd. Use your Windows repair disk(s) for each version of Windows to reinstall Windows boot loaders to MBRs. You may be able to use Boot-Repair's advanced mode to choose.

Comment: OK. I corrected problems with list of systems exept ubuntu in boot menu, but I lost windows proffesional in this list, that I need.

Details:
When I started Windows boot USB it showed window that
there are 3 windows:
Windows 7 on C
Windows 7 Proffesional on on unknows device
Windows 7 Ultimate on F

and then asked if i want to correct mistakes.
I chose OK and windows professional disappeared from this list and when I rebooted it disappeared from boot list.

Comment: Grub only boots Windows that have boot files. And multiple installs of Windows only have boot files in one primary partition with the boot flag. Other Windows installs will be in Windows BCD. Only if Windows is in primary partition can you move boot flag and run repairs to add boot files. Then grub will also see that as bootable.